# Time complexity of number base conversion

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, big-o, time-complexity

The answer for [problem 8.3-4](https://www.cs.arizona.edu/classes/cs445/spring06/hw2-solutions.pdf):

> 8. 8.3-4 (from CLRS) Show how to sort n integers in range 0 to n^2 − 1 in O(n) time.

The answer:

> First take O(n) time to convert the integers into 2-digits numbers
>   base n ....

It assumes that we can get convert `n` integers in the range 0 to `n^2-1`  to base `n` in `O(n)` time ?

How is this possible ?

Shouldn't each conversion take O(log(n)) time and hence for n conversions the time should be O(nlogn) rather than O(n) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the author meant each integer arithmetic is done in `O(1)` time, so converting a number to base `n` is basically most significant digit: `x/n`, lease significant digit: `x%n`, which under the above assumption is done in constant time.

Without the given assumption, each number needs `log(n^2)=2log(n)` bits to be represented, so only reading the input is going to take `O(nlogn)` time, so this assumption is needed to meet the time requirement.

Comment: I guess the idea is that the highest integer that we have been given is n^3 so the worst case time for that is O(1) because we know that we only have to find 3 digits, so we can claim constant time for all digits.

Comment: @DeepankarArya The question is about n^2-1, not n^3-1. The same applies for n^3-1 with 3 digits though.

Comment: Actually, in CLRS 3r ed they changed it to n^3, but anyways it doesn't matter here. Any n^k, where k is a known constant, will work I guess.